# error with setup openstack Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, openstack

I was trying to install OpenStack on Ubuntu. I followed all steps and all was going great until the last line which says: " ./stack.sh "  but in the end, I got this error that says devstack should be run as a user with sudo permissions, not root.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user with **sudo** privileges and use that user to run `./stack.sh`

For more detailed information and steps: 
**https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/#add-stack-user**